# ProGaurd:Classes getting delete which are indirectly referenced to external libraries

Tags: android, performance, proguard, android-proguard

I am using javaCV library for video creation in android.Its working while

```
minifyEnabled false
```

but if I am using proguard(All the indirectly referenced files are getting deleted) Its crashing with below error while creating video

> 01-22 18:22:39.503 31713-31869/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'java.awt.image.BufferedImage', referenced from method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.cloneBufferedImage
>   01-22 18:22:39.503 31713-31869/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'java.awt.Rectangle', referenced from method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.copyFrom
>   01-22 18:22:39.503 31713-31869/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'java.awt.Rectangle', referenced from method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.copyTo
>   01-22 18:22:39.523 31713-31869/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'java.awt.image.BufferedImage', referenced from method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.getBufferedImage
>   01-22 18:22:39.523 31713-31869/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel', referenced from method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.getBufferedImage
>   01-22 18:22:39.523 31713-31869/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'java.awt.image.BufferedImage', referenced from method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.getBufferedImage
>   01-22 18:22:39.523 31713-31869/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'java.awt.image.BufferedImage', referenced from method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.getBufferedImage
>   01-22 18:22:39.523 31713-31869/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel', referenced from method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.getBufferedImage
>   01-22 18:22:39.523 31713-31869/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel', referenced from method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.getBufferedImage
>   01-22 18:22:39.523 31713-31869/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel', referenced from method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.getBufferedImage
>   01-22 18:22:39.523 31713-31869/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel', referenced from method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.getBufferedImage
>   01-22 18:22:39.523 31713-31869/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'java.awt.image.ComponentColorModel', referenced from method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.getBufferedImage
>   01-22 18:22:39.523 31713-31869/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'java.awt.image.BufferedImage', referenced from method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.getBufferedImage
>   01-22 18:22:39.523 31713-31869/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'java.awt.image.BufferedImage', referenced from method com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$IplImage.getBufferedImage

Comment: I haven't used the library. May be you need to add some rules to keep them from obfuscating. A quick search and found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21478125/prograurding-android-project-using-javacv-gives-exception

Comment: I have added for those files.But classes in java.awt.image.** which are used in library is getting delete even after adding -keep java.awt.image.**{*;}.

Comment: I have not used that library so i cannot comment any further. But look at what rules you need to provide so that it does not crash